# How do instance objects see the private members of function's an object parameter?

Tags: c++, object, reference, private-members

Header File (.h):

```
bool canTravelWith(const Passenger&) const;
```

Implementation File (.cpp):

```
bool Passenger::canTravelWith(const Passenger& x) const
    {
        bool canTravel = false;

        //if both passengers have the same destination on the same date...
        if (strcmp(x.m_destination,this->m_destination) == 0 && x.m_year == this->m_year && x.m_month == this->m_month && x.m_day == this->m_day)
        {
            canTravel = true;
        }

        return canTravel;
    }
```

Hey guys,

The code above works but what I wanted to know is if the parameter's object's members are privately accessed; how am I able to call that object's members inside my canTravelWith()?

In any other cases; I wouldn't be able to call an object's private members.

I want to understand why that is.

Thanks. (:

Comment: I am confused, you are accessing the private members of your class? What is the problem with that?

Comment: So, you are asking why can you access `Passenger` class' private members from within the `Passenger` class? What? Consider reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It is accessible because the object itself was passed as a reference to the function.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `private` and `protected` do not restrict you from accessing those sorts of properties or functions from *within the same class*.

This is a `Passenger` function so it has full access to everything. That there are two instances of an object in play does not restrict you. `private` does not mean other instances can't touch it, only other classes.

Answer (score 0):

That's because a private member is a private member of a class, not an instance.

This is the same thing as asking why you can access the private member of `this`, since `this` is a pointer passed as parameter to your function, but simply hidden.

To put that in perspective, consider this code:

```
bool Passenger::canTravelWith(const Passenger& x) const
{
    Passenger const* ptr = this;

    // ptr is this, of course I can access private stuff!
    (void) ptr->m_destination;

    if (rand() % 10) {
        ptr = &x;
    }

    // Is the compiler will really try to guess if ptr
    // still points to this? privateness is a compile time
    // property of the class, not runtime.
    (void) ptr->m_destination;
}
```

Also, accessing private member don't require an instance at all:

```
struct Passenger {
private:
    static constexpr int value() { return 42; }

public:
    static constexpr int v = value();
};
```

As you can see, we are creating a static variable that his value came from a private static function. But since we are in *the scope* of the class, we can access it. Here's another example:

```
struct Outer {
private:
    int value = 42;

public:
    struct Inner {
        int getPrivate(Outer& o) { return o.value; }
    };
};

int main() {
    Outer o;
    Outer::Inner i;

    int v = i.getPrivate(o);
}
```

As you can see, `Inner` access private members of `Outer`, whithout being a friend. This is simply because `Inner` is inside the scope of the class.